# Downgrade PHP 7.4.2. to 7.1.3, 7.2.0, 7.3.0

Tags: php, magento, mamp

During the 'Readiness Check' installing Magento 1.x , the only thing scuppering me is the PHP version check.

My Mac (utilising Mamp Pro) is using PHP 7.4.2. and I need to downgrade to either PHP 7.1.3, 7.2.0 or 7.3.0.

I have tried many things via the Terminal but have not managed to downgrade PHP.

Can anyone point me in the right direction/offer advice?

Answer (score 3):

It happened with me as well. Please follow these simple steps and I assume there are lower versions in your MAMP php folder.

**STEP 1:** Goto `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php` rename the PHP 7.4.2 folder to something that MAMP can't recognise it. Example: latest-php.7.4.2

**STEP 2:** Quit MAMP application

**STEP 3:** Start again the MAMP application and goto to Preferences > PHP to select your default PHP. MAMP will show latest available PHP versions.

[image]